# Combine nested list entries

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with stock index data (which I load from a database) as follows:

```
lis={{{2000,01,03,^AEX", 4470}, {2000,01,05, ^AEX, 4470}}, 
    {{2000,01,04, ^AFLI, 4471}, {2000,01,05, ^AFLI, 4471}},
    {{2000,01,03,^AORD, 4472}, {2000,01,05, ^AORD, 4472}}}
```

I would like to update the database. For that purpose I need the date of the last database entry per symbol. I use the following function:

```
updateParameter =
 Map[
  Flatten[{
     Last[Transpose[#][[1]]],
     #[[1, 2]],
     #[[1, 3]]
     }] &, lis]
```

It provide the desired result:

```
{{2015,01,05, ^AEX, 4470}, {2015,01,05, ^AFLI, 
  4471}, {2015,01,05, ^AORD, 4472}}
```

But my function seems to be a little bit awkward. I´m sure there is a more "elegant" way. Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: `lis[[All, -1]]` will give you same result...